# Gurobi/Python crashes with "A heap has been corrupted" error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, gurobi

I am running an optimization in Gurobi which crashes whenever I add a quadratic constraint to the problem that I generate thru the following lines of code:

```
expression = gurobipy.QuadExpr()
for course_key in hostings:
    for kitchen_key in hostings[course_key]:
        if not hostings[course_key][kitchen_key].large_gathering:

expression.add(x[kitchen_key,course_key,team_key1]*x[kitchen_key,course_key,team_key2])

mod.addQConstr(expression,gurobipy.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,1,"1MeetingPerPair_"+team_key1+"_"+team_key2)
```

The optimization always crashes after three iterations:

[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XSeX.png)

with the following error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC596CE6FC (ntdll.dll) in python.exe:
0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FF8FF82C6E0).
```

Does anyone have any clue as to how this problem could be solved? I am rather clueless as to what the error message even wants to tell me. I tried constructing the constraint in different ways (e. g. using .add instead of .addTerms) but that didn't change anything. Appreciate any help!

Comment: That's quite some error and to me that's something more for Gurobi's support-team, their official user-forum (but some people are active readers here too). Blindly guessing (without having used gurobi for a while), this really looks like a problem during gurobi's solving-process (not python, but C/C++/Fortran; who knows). I also think, that usual problems like not-enough-ram/diskspace problems would result in a more faithful error. That makes this strange. For people helping debugging: add more information about your gurobi/python versions, OS, params and so on and how the setup was being done

Comment: Thanks for your remarks! I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017. My gurobi version is 8.0 but I had the same problem with 7.5.2 (I upgraded after the problem occured, hoping that would fix the issue). Since I am relatively new to gurobi and python I have no clue which other settings/parameters may be interessting so please bear with me and tell me in case you require additional info and where to find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report for the Gurobi software developers - please contact Gurobi support directly.